# Permissions required for Outlook / Exchange conference room management

Tags: exchange, outlook, email

In outlook, when scheduling a meeting, I can see the attendees of any meeting that I schedule. 
Is there any way to see the attendees/organizers for meetings that are scheduled in common rooms (conference rooms)? I would assume that its a permissions issue, but that may not be entirely correct.